# Merge a CSV file data cells according to the data format

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file with around 1 Million rows. 
Let say its have details like

```
Name      |   Age   | Salary 
name 1      52       10000
name 2      55       10043 
name 3      50       100054
name 2      55       10023
name 1      52       100322...
```

and soon .

but i need to merge the redundant details .
and need a output like

```
Name      |   Age   | Salary 
name 1      52       110322*
name 2      55       20066 *
name 3      50       100054
```

you might notice that the repeating Name 1 and Name 2 details are merged and the Salary values are added .So i'm looking for a way to apply this change to my original data set. so i need a python script to fix my problem .

Comment: Show your not working code.

Comment: I don't see a question here.  Only requirements.  Is there a question?

Answer (score 1):

First, you are not merging but aggregating the dataset.

Consider using the [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html) package. Import the csv as a data frame then use group by sum() function to aggregate the Salary field and other quantity values. Apply same principle to other relevent fields:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('C:\\Path\\To\\InputCSV.csv')

newdf = df.groupby('Name', 'Age').sum()

newdf = to_csv('C:\\Path\\To\\OutputCSV.csv')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
>>> data_merged = data.groupby(['Name', 'Age']).sum().reset_index()
>>> data_merged

    Name   Age  Salary 
0  name 1   52   110322
1  name 2   55    20066
2  name 3   50   100054
```